# How to open Emacs window in Android L?

Tags: installation, text-editor

I have installed Emacs 1.0.1 from Google Play on Android 5.0.2 on Sony Xperia Z3 Compact. When I try to run it all I'm seeing is a notification "Terminal session is running" but I don't have any terminal window open.

Comment: One of the reviews mentions that it works if run under Terminal IDE, but that app says it doesn't support 5.0 either.  You could try [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) since the emacs app is based off it.

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me "unknown error 505" when I try to install it.